# How to create a grid containing all possible parameters for a function?

Tags: python

I have the following parameters:

```py
trend_types = ['add', 'mul']
seasonal_types = ['add', 'mul']
boxcox_options = [True, False, 'log']
```

To be used in the following function:

```py
model = sm.tsa.ExponentialSmoothing(df, trend=trend_type, seasonal=seasonal_type, use_boxcox=boxcox)
fittedModel = model.fit()
```

And I would like to generate an array containing all possible combinations, like:

```json
[
    {trend_type: 'add', seasonal_type: 'add', boxcox: True},
    {trend_type: 'add', seasonal_type: 'add', boxcox: False},
    {trend_type: 'add', seasonal_type: 'add', boxcox: Log},
    {trend_type: 'add', seasonal_type: 'mul', boxcox: True},
    {trend_type: 'add', seasonal_type: 'mul', boxcox: False},
    {trend_type: 'add', seasonal_type: 'mul', boxcox: Log},
    [..]
]
```

That way I can use such an array like:

```py
for parameter in parameters:
    model = sm.tsa.ExponentialSmoothing(df, trend=parameter.trend_type, seasonal=parameter.seasonal_type, use_boxcox=parameter.boxcox)
    fittedModel = model.fit()
```

Is there a way to generate such an array?

Comment: Python is not Javascript, `parameter.trend_type` etc would not work with the *list of dictionaries* you show. But there is no need to create the dictionaries in the first place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

trend_types = ["add", "mul"]
seasonal_types = ["add", "mul"]
boxcox_options = [True, False, "log"]

for t, s, b in product(trend_types, seasonal_types, boxcox_options):
    print(t, s, b)
```

Prints:

```
add add True
add add False
add add log
add mul True
add mul False
add mul log
mul add True
mul add False
mul add log
mul mul True
mul mul False
mul mul log
```